# OO performance question

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I will be quick and simple on this.
Basically I need to merge multiple Invoices(Object) quickly and fast.

A simple idea is to

```
$invoice1 = new Invoice(1);
$invoice2 = new Invoice(2);
$invoice3 = new Invoice(3);
$invoice1->merge($invoice2,invoice3);
$invoice1->save();
```

Since each object will query it's own data, the number of queries increase as the number of invoices needed to be merge increases.

However, this is a case where a single query

```
SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

Will suffice, however the implementation will not be as elegant as the above.

Initial benchmarks on sample data indicates a 2.5x-3x decrease in speed on the above due to the sheer number of mysql queries.

Advice please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an Invoice factory. You ask it for invoices using various methods. newest(n) get(id) get(array(id,id,id)) so on, and it returns arrays of invoices or single invoice objects.

```
<?php
    $invoice56 = InvoiceFactory::Get(56); // Get's invoice 56
    $invoices = InvoiceFactory::Newest(25); // Get's an array of the newest 25 invoices
?>
```

Comment: Also, take a look at [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) in order let the same implementation handle `Get(id)`, `Get(idA, idB)`, and `Get(id1, id2, ... idN)`.

Comment: that is an option, although typically I prefer not to do that because the array tells someone coming across the method in use what it does and accepts without looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make the `Invoice` object lazy and let `merge` load everything that hasn't been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you work on the same db connection all the time. Check that it does not reconnect in one script execution thread.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest looking into using an actual ORM (object relational mapping) in order to create a seperation between your actual queries and the objects used.. Take a look at Propel or (my favorite) Doctrine (version 2 is *very* easy to use)

That way you could have exactly what you want in just the same amount of code...